# What are best tactics to get pre-subscribers to an app soon to be released for a local market?

Tags: applications, users, marketing, app, audience

The title says it all. Any and all tips / tactics you found that worked for you when getting an app out there are welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing and promotion.

Comment: I tried to find the right place to post this question in the StackExchange network but UX was the closest related topic I could find. Where can I put it?

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov This question isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange - SE sites are question and answer sites, not forums.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am trying to get the best possible tactics in one answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best way which worked for us (SettleApp - little indie app) was recommendation by friends and more importantely by influential friends. When they spread the word on their twitter accounts, blog, fb pages,... It can help a lot.

After launch a good idea is to ask for reviews on the local sites that are willing to write about local apps. (This works really well. Especially when you live in small country.)

Comment: Thank you. It's roughly what I was thinking as well. However friends sharing the post about the app hasn't helped me much. Posting in all the related Facebook groups is the only tactic that works so far.